# Is the app's displayed name taken from iTunesConnect or the project name in XCode

Tags: ios, app-store

My app name I want to show up on users iPhone is not in english. My project name in xcode is "MyApp". In itunes connect under app name I've entered the right name I want to show up after a user installs my app. What is the appname the user will see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the name that will be shown can be set in the **info.plist** with the tag

**Bundle display name**

Build Settings for project to set target file:

[image]

and in "Info" add the part

**Bundle display name** *String* "MyCustomName"

You may also add a localized file named **InfoPlist.strings** and insert

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "MyCustomName";
```

for every locale ;)

Answer (score 0):

The name that will shop up under your icon on the user's device is determined by the Info.plist.

By default, this is the same as your Product name in the project build settings:

[image]

but you can change this to whatever you'd like:

[image]

*Note that a long name like my example, will be truncated.. you won't see all of that text.

---

<strike>I think there is also a way to localise the name that is shown. I don't know how to do this, but if someone does, please feel free to edit this answer.</strike>

And for completeness, this is taken from geo's answer:

You may also add a localized file named **InfoPlist.strings** and insert

```
CFBundleDisplayName = "MyCustomName";
```

for every locale

Comment: After some reading I think it should be B"undle Display name", not Bundle name like your pic suggests.

Answer (score 0):

In the App Store, they will see the name you have entered in iTUnes Connect, in the iDevices, they will see the name that you put in Info.plist file under 'Bundle display name'. If you didn't put anything under 'Bundle display name', then they will see the project name on their devices.